# Api to Api Comunication and data transformation

Tags: rest, api, soap, powerbuilder

Good day,

I want to communicate between two Web Api's, the first web api lets call Api1 not written by me and that api interacts with my data base to spit out information needed. 
I have web api2 which would be written by me and why i have this is because my application needs data in certain kind of format (.dll) format.so api2 purpose is to get the information from api1 and then transform or package my data in a way that the my application would understand.

The question, is this possible?. can i use wrappers, so when i get my information from api1 then i wrap my information in the desired format before sending it off to the application. Does anyone have any other suggestions ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What does _data in dll-format_ actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

**What you describe is possible** but the requirements are too vague to give a useful answer.

The file extension doesn't really mean anything so not sure why you need .dll format for the message. I would use a standard format like Json or Xml. Or if using datawindow you could simply do saveas on sending side (or comma delimited, tab delimit) and file import on receiving end, so many options.

**Too vague.**

1. Async or Sync interface?
2. Files transferred via REST, OLE, DDE, or files written to location on server?
3. Are the files/data transferred specific to a logged in user?
4. How much data is being transferred, rows of information or configuration data? Answer will help in deciding on appropriate format & best method.
5. What type program is API #1 not in your control? That is important factor.